# Negative Meta Post

Tags: cipher

**Behold, the first *(predictably negatively scored)* meta post on the main site.**

> To puzzle posters of this site:
>
> 123##456 sacrifices 123#456.
> If you're going to focus on 123##456 over 123#456, you should 1245.

**Rules:**
Uncover the context of the above "meta post", where each number represents a unique character, and each hashtag covers one character.

---

*For example:*

> My 123#45 makes 12345 for me by doing tricks.

*Would bear the answer:*

> My monkey makes money for me by doing tricks.

*(Note: The hashtags can also contain characters assigned to a number, and there can be multiple hashtags with the same value.)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The message is

> '**QUANTITY** sacrifices **QUALITY**. If you're going to focus on **QUANTITY** over **QUALITY**, you should **QUIT**.

So

> 1 = Q
> 2 = U
> 3 = A
> 4 = I
> 5 = T
> 6 = Y
> # = N,T,L